# should a section base class be used as a Hook in css?

Tags: html, css

I have a navbar and the following HTML markup for it :

```
<!-- Fixed navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt=""></a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about-us.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">Why Join</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>

    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

now shoud all the css selections start with the .navbar class ? eg .

```
.navbar .navbar-header

.navbar .navbar-brand

.navbar .navbar-right
```

my question here is suppose you have a section , like say gallery , which has a class of .gallery as the upper most parent element. now should all the elements listed inside this section be styled using the .gallery class s the base selector? is this a good convention? if not what is a better convention? what is a better css selector convention, especially when building a large scale site?

Comment: Will you have different styles for `.navbar`s under `.gallery` and those under other sections?

Comment: @Itay , i basically build sites between  1 - 20 pages , i am more interested in knowing whats the good convention for sites with huge amouths of pages  ! Its a very important for me to know .

Comment: i am aware of the fact that nesting a class under a class is considered bad convention by many espically because tht reduces the scope of a class , also it prevents the class selector from being globally available !

Comment: It's not a "bad" convention. It's perfectly acceptable. Things need scope, things need to be nested. The problem lies in everything being nested under something for reasons without gain.

Comment: @ChristianHain U have a fair point !

Comment: You can learn it from the CSS source of Bootstrap if you're using the framework. It's more about rewriting the rules, you'll have to use multiple classes in order to do so. If you want to ask it for a general case, you should not posting a Bootstrap markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My OPINION would be no, you should not prefix your selector with `.navbar` as high specificity is generally a bad idea and leads to less maintainable code.  If I understand your question correctly one suggestion would be to set up your css like this.

```
//For common styling
.navbar-header{}

//For the styles specific to your code snippet
.navbar-header--top {}

//For the styles specific to your gallery code 
.navbar-header--gallery {}
```

And then in your HTML you would do

```
<div class="navbar-header navbar-header--top">
<div class="navbar-header navbar-header--gallery">
```

This has a much more thorough explanation as to why, as well as some other principles that may be of interest to you.

http://cssguidelin.es/#css-selectors

Comment: what ur suggesting if i am right is that apply the generic style to `navbar-header` and the more specific style to `navbar-header--top` , which is exactly what most frameworks do ... and you say that good ? but is't that cluttering the HTML code then , this seems like a better approch though then nesting under the sections parent class !

Comment: Yes, that is my suggestion.  You could say it is cluttering the HTML, I would say that this is a small tradeoff for increased readability (in terms of how your css relates to the HTML) and increased maintainability of your CSS.  I'd strongly suggest reading that link as it covers a lot of these areas and I think provides good explanations as to WHY.

Comment: The code needs to go somewhere. It's easier to understand what pieces are doing what if your CSS is clean, instead of tracing specificity overrides.

Answer (score 1):

It will work, but it's unnecessary. `.navbar-header` is already specific enough. If you scope all your classes under `.navbar`, you're adding an extra level of specificity, as well as eight extra characters per declaration that you don't need.

If you were trying to style a generic class uniquely for navbar, such as `.icon-bar`, then you would need that extra level of specificity, or a unique class name for those elements.

That being said, you may wonder why you see other people adding base classes at all, such as `.navbar .navbar-default`. In this example, `.navbar` will have base styling applied to it, and `.navbar-default` will extend that and add new styles.